# Sending Files From Vuex to Backend using Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex

I have a vuex which stores few informations and also the files uploaded by the users. Now I am trying to send all the `vuex` data to backend using axios to process it but for some reason the file array is empty.

But when I see in VueDevTools, there is a file object in the vuex state.

This is my axios call, it is just not images which I am trying to send.

```js
axios.post('/admin/form/saveForm',{
    data : this.$store.getters.getEditCollector,
    formData: this.$store.getters.getCollector,
    formName : this.formName,
    task: this.task,
    id: this.formEntryId,
    formId: this.formId,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
.then(response => {})
.catch(error => {});
```

My Vuex is below snapshot.[image]

As we can see, the logo state has a File Object, but when the request is received in the backend( PHP- Laravel), It is an empty array.

What is wrong here? Can someone point out the mistake?

EDIT1: Added Network Payload

[image]

EDIT2: Added Backend Code - Laravel

```php
public function saveForm(Request $request){
    // form data here has logo but empty array  <------
    $formData = $request->input('data');

    $wholeFormData = $request->input('formData');
    $this->formID = $request->input('formId');

    ....
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you get on the backend and the code please?

Comment: Could you include the request you see in the Network section of your browser's developer tools? The code you posted seems to have the `headers` included in the request data, rather than in the request options.

Comment: I have added the network payload @skirtle

Comment: Added the code which you asked for @GeorgeHanson

Comment: You can't transfer a file using a JSON upload. I suggest you do some research into building a `FormData` object that can then be sent as the request body. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: But I am adding the header  multipart/form-data which is not json